# Issue with Zombie wait function

Tags: node.js

I am currently trying to implement following code with [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API#browser-wait-callback). Yet, I am unable to make the following code to work:

```
var Browser = require('zombie');

browser = new Browser();
browser.wait(3000, function() { console.log("ok"); });
```

So, the script should wait 3 seconds before displaying "ok". Yet, it displays it immediately.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states:

> Waits for the browser to complete loading resources and processing
>   JavaScript events.

Since you're not requesting anything, there's nothing to wait for, so Zombie calls the callback immediately. It's more of a maximum timeout kind of thing, not a guaranteed wait.